# ios Custom multiple selection for tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table that has three sections in it. There are 4 rows per section. I want one selection per section which makes for 3 selections for the whole table. I'm trying to do this using the following functions that I made which reset the current section and sets the new selection.

```
- (void)selectOneRow:(int)row inSection:(int)section
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

    for(int i = 0; i < [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:section] count]; ++i) {
        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
        [self.table deselectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:NO];
        //[[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip] setHighlighted:NO];
    }

    [self.table selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    //[[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setHighlighted:YES];

    [self disableInteractionForRow:row inSection:section];
}

- (void)disableInteractionForRow:(int)row inSection:(int)section
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

    for(int i = 0; i < [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:section] count]; ++i) {
        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
        [[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }

    [[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

An example of selecting the first row of the first section is:

```
[self selectOneRow:0 inSection:0];
```

This works great the first time, but every time afterword it turns the row off, leaving the section blank. How can I fix this? Or am I going about this all wrong in the first place? Thanks for you help.

** EDIT adding an image **

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to make it too complicated. Instead of putting three choices in one table view with three sections, make three separate tables and three separate views.

For example, go to the settings app on the iPhone. Tap "Mail, Contacts, Calendars", and then scroll down to the options "Show", "Preview", and "Minimum Font Size" under the "Mail" section title. For each one of those settings, a new view is pushed with a new table view controller, and you can only select one of the options and then go back. That keeps the interface clean, not to mention your code.

Hopefully restructuring it like this will work better for you. I don't know if I can say that the way you're doing it now is wrong, but it's not consistent with how Apple structures their apps.

Comment: I should point out that these are toggle-able buttons. You select a button and it turns on. Select another button and the prior button will deselect.

Comment: Is it similar to HTML radio buttons? Maybe you could post a screenshot of what you mean. The table views with the checkmarks should have the same function as toggle buttons if I understand what you mean.

Comment: I just added a photo. I started it again from scratch and it works like expected now, but I still think there is a better way..